# Removing rows in which all but one column are empty

Tags: r

with the following code:

```
data <- rbind(c(1,1,2,3),
          c(1,1, NA, 4), 
          c(1,4,6,7), 
          c(1,NA, NA, NA), 
          c(1,4, 8, NA))
```

I would like to remove the rows in which columns 2-4 are NA.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you specify your condition better? You want to exclude rows where col.2 AND col.4 are both NA or at least one of the two is NA or something else ... ? Also, does "2-4" mean columns "2,3,4" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do in this way:

```
filteredData <- data[!is.na(data[,2]) | !is.na(data[,4]),]

> data
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    2    3
[2,]    1    1   NA    4
[3,]    1    4    6    7
[4,]    1   NA   NA   NA
[5,]    1    4    8   NA

> filteredData
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    2    3
[2,]    1    1   NA    4
[3,]    1    4    6    7
[4,]    1    4    8   NA
```

Comment: @LinaBird: please note that this code considers just column 2 and 4, excluding the 3rd. As I asked in my comment, you should specify better your condition since it's not completely clear...

Answer (score 2):

another way:

```
 data[! rowSums(is.na(data[,2:4])) == 3, ]
```

If it was just columns 2 **and** 4 then it would be:

```
data[! rowSums(is.na(data[,c(2,4)])) == 2, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the rows where all values in columns 2-4 are `NA`:

```
data[apply(data[,2:4],1,function(x) !all(is.na(x))),]

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    2    3
[2,]    1    1   NA    4
[3,]    1    4    6    7
[4,]    1    4    8   NA
```

To just exclude the first column from the columns that are checked for `NA`'s, you could use a negative index like:

```
data[apply(data[,-1],1,function(x) !all(is.na(x))),]
```